# Data Studio - Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword LIMIT at [68:8]

Tags: looker-studio

Hi when I write the following query in BigQuery it executes but when I try to add it in Data Studio I get the following error: Data Studio - Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword LIMIT at [68:8]

can anyone tell me how I correct it run in Data Studio?

```
if( EXTRACT(month  FROM current_Date) = 9) then
 (SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year` 
where LCRNEngland <> '-' and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01' and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-08-31'
group by LCRNEngland order by total );

elseif( EXTRACT(month  FROM current_Date) = 10) then
(SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year` 
where LCRNEngland <> '-' and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01' and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-09-30' group by LCRNEngland order by total );

elseif( EXTRACT(month  FROM current_Date) = 11) then
 (SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year` 
where LCRNEngland <> '-' and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01' and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-10-31' group by LCRNEngland order by total );

elseif( EXTRACT(month  FROM current_Date) = 12) then
 (SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year` 
where LCRNEngland <> '-' and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01' and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-11-31' group by LCRNEngland order by total );

elseif( EXTRACT(month  FROM current_Date) = 1) then
 (SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year` 
where LCRNEngland <> '-' and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01' and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-12-31' group by LCRNEngland order by total );

elseif( EXTRACT(month  FROM current_Date) = 2) then
 (SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year` 
where LCRNEngland <> '-' and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01' and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2021-01-31' group by LCRNEngland order by total );

elseif( EXTRACT(month  FROM current_Date) = 3) then
 (SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year` 
where LCRNEngland <> '-' and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01' and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2021-02-28' group by LCRNEngland order by total );

elseif( EXTRACT(month  FROM current_Date) = 4) then
 (SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year` 
where LCRNEngland <> '-' and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01' and cast(RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2021-03-31' group by LCRNEngland order by total );

end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Apparently google adds limit clause as standard. But before adding it searches for limit statement within your code. So you need to add within comments and it will work as below:

```
if
    (EXTRACT(month FROM current_Date) = 9)
    then
(SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total
 FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year`
 where LCRNEngland <> '-'
   and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01'
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-08-31'
 group by LCRNEngland
 order by total);

elseif
    (EXTRACT(month FROM current_Date) = 10)
    then
(SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total
 FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year`
 where LCRNEngland <> '-'
   and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01'
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-09-30'
 group by LCRNEngland
 order by total);

elseif
    (EXTRACT(month FROM current_Date) = 11)
    then
(SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total
 FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year`
 where LCRNEngland <> '-'
   and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01'
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-10-31'
 group by LCRNEngland
 order by total);

elseif
    (EXTRACT(month FROM current_Date) = 12)
    then
(SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total
 FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year`
 where LCRNEngland <> '-'
   and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01'
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-11-31'
 group by LCRNEngland
 order by total);

elseif
    (EXTRACT(month FROM current_Date) = 1)
    then
(SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total
 FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year`
 where LCRNEngland <> '-'
   and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01'
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2020-12-31'
 group by LCRNEngland
 order by total);

elseif
    (EXTRACT(month FROM current_Date) = 2)
    then
(SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total
 FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year`
 where LCRNEngland <> '-'
   and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01'
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2021-01-31'
 group by LCRNEngland
 order by total);

elseif
    (EXTRACT(month FROM current_Date) = 3)
    then
(SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total
 FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year`
 where LCRNEngland <> '-'
   and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01'
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2021-02-28'
 group by LCRNEngland
 order by total);

elseif
    (EXTRACT(month FROM current_Date) = 4)
    then
(SELECT LCRNEngland, sum(RecruitmentCount) as Total
 FROM `optical-mind-258908.WM.LCRN_Confirmed_Recruitment_Current_Year`
 where LCRNEngland <> '-'
   and Study_IsUrgentPublicHealthResearch = false
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) >= '2020-04-01'
   and cast (RecruitmentDate as date) <= '2021-03-31'
 group by LCRNEngland
 order by total);

end if;
/* LIMIT 100 */
```